# How To Change JTable After Initialization?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im pretty new to Swing development in Java. I need some help with populating a table with some values that I have, after the initialization is done.

```
someClass extends JPanel{
private JLabel something;
static private JTable Table;
private JPanel temp;

someClass(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    selectSong = new JLabel("some text");
    temp = new JPanel();
    temp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    temp.add(something);
    Table = new JTable();
    //Table.setVisible(false);
    add(temp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(new JScrollPane(Table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
static void populateTable(ArrayList<String> list){
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dtm.addColumn("title", list.toArray());
    Table = new JTable(dtm);
    Table.setVisible(true);
    new someClass().add(new JScrollPane(Table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
```

This class called someClass is a subclass of JPanel. I am using an object of this and appending it to the Main Frame(not shown here). According to this, initially a GUI form is created with an empty table, and after some operations are done, I call the populateTable function, I want this to change the values of the table to have one column (named title) and containing the arraylist elements in the subsequent rows.

Comment: why do you create a new table, if you want to populate the existing one?

Comment: Why do you call your `JTable` 'Table'? It should add least start with a lowercase character.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) The answer to your general question is 'change the model, not the table'. 4) Avoid `static` unless you can explain why it's a good thing to use. 5) Make the table model a class attribute & provide an accessor. 6) Those points are in no particular order. 7) Don't ..

Comment: ,, extend components unless there is a good case for doing so (same as using `static` for components).

Comment: @Thibstars this isn't my actual code,  I've changed all the identifiers to suit the purpose.  Don't mind all the small mistakes

Comment: @aelop, could you tell me how to populate the existing one then?  I need to populate it after stuff is done, not when the someClass()  constructor is invoked

Comment: have a look at my answer. in my answer you will only add columns. if you want to fill by rows. you need to call `dtm.addRow(list);`. in that case, you need to specify the column headers at initialization and list.size()-1 should always be equal to amount of column headers (not totally sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you called your `JTable` 'table':

```
static void populateTable(ArrayList<String> list){
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dtm.addColumn("title", list.toArray());
        table.setModel(dtm);
    }
    }
```

You should also not call `table.setVisible(true);` in that method, as it has nothing to do with populating the table.

**Edit:** as suggested by others: it would also be better to make use of a class attribute for the `DefaultTableModel`.

Answer (score 1):

```
someClass extends JPanel{
    private JLabel something;
    static private JTable Table;
    private JPanel temp;
    private DefaultTableModel dtm;

    someClass(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        selectSong = new JLabel("some text");
        temp = new JPanel();
        temp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        temp.add(something);
        dtm= new DefaultTableModel();
        Table = new JTable(dtm);
        add(temp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(new JScrollPane(Table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
    static void populateTable(ArrayList<String> list){
        dtm.addColumn("title", list.toArray());
    }
    }
```

this is how your class should look like

Answer (score 0):

You should use fireTableDataChanged method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged()